# Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never'. typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

i've trying to show image from JSON api and then show it to page, i was do it succesfully but for some reason when i go to page i've get this errors

```
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never'.
Property 'url' does not exist on type 'never'.
Property 'title' does not exist on type 'never'.
```

here is the code

```
 const App = () => {
 const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
 useEffect(() => {
 fetch('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?breed_id=abys')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => setImages(json))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
, []);
return (
<Fragment>
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Image Gallery</h1>
    <div className="image-container">
      {images.map(image => (
        <Image key={image.id} image={image.url} alt={image.title} />
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
</Fragment>
);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You havent declared a type for `image` in your `useState`

```
const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
```

so it is considered as type `never`.

What you should do is add an interface eg `IImage` and then declare it in your `useState`

```
export default interface IImage {
  id: number
  url: string
  title: string
}

const [images, setImages] = useState<IImage[]>([]);
```